# Local scope in if-else statement in swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, scope

I just found a small inconsistent behaviour in my ios app, about local scope.

A person can register itself for an event when there are seats left. In this case `OnWaitingList` and `OnWaitingListAt` is **not** defined.

When no seats are left the person can get on a waiting list. If the user accepts (clicks OK) OnWaitingList is set to true and OnWaitingListAt to unixtime. In either case saved to the same DynamoDB table.

A person can register itself to multiple events.

What I found out was when a person **first** gets on a waiting list (no seats left) and **then** registers itself to another event (seats left) OnWaitingList is false and OnWaitingListAt is 0, the initial values in the class-definition. These two values are then saved as well.

A `participant` variable is defined inside the brackets {} in the if and else statement.

I assumed scope was bound to the brackets and allow me to have two variables with the same name and possible different values as stated in [this](https://andybargh.com/lifetime-scope-and-namespaces-in-swift/#Local_or_Nested_Scope) article. I may be wrong but it seems this cross-pollination should not happen under this circumstance.

Two variables with different names will solve this issue. It does not break the flow but it's annoying since I can't figure out why this happens.

```
if (still seats left) {
    let participant = self.createParticipant(self.items[indexPath.row])

    dynamoDBObjectMapper.save(participant).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        Register person
        return nil
    })
} else { // Offer people to sign up on a waiting list.
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let waitingListAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let participant = self.createParticipant(self.items[indexPath.row])
        participant.OnWaitingList = true
        participant.OnWaitingListAt = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

        dynamoDBObjectMapper.save(participant).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            Register person with OnWaitingList and OnWaitingListAt set
            return nil
        })
    })
}

func createParticipant(item: AggregatedEvents) -> Participants {
    let participant = Participants()
    participant?.Timestamp = String(item.timestamp!)
    participant?.Id = self.fbId
    participant?.Date = item.date!
    participant?.Event = item.event!
    participant?.Location = item.location!
    participant?.Name = self.name
    participant?.Time = item.time!

    return participant!
}

class Participants: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
    var Timestamp: NSString?  // Partition key.
    var Id: NSString?         // Sort key.

    var Date: NSString? = "28. okt. 1967"
    var Event: NSString? = "PT-AMOK Trening"
    var Location: NSString? = "Breim"
    var Name: NSString? = "Claus Guttesen"
    var Time: NSString? = "19:00"
    var OnWaitingList: NSNumber? = false
    var OnWaitingListAt: NSNumber? = 0.0
}
```

Comment: Renaming any of your `participant` variables will make no difference in any behavior. They are all already different variables.

Comment: Unrelated nitpick - why is your `Participants` class name plural? Each instance represents one participant. The class should be named `Participant`.

Comment: @rmaddy Which is how I thought scope worked. The class maps to a DynamoDB table which is named Participants.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the values from being stored I set them to nil.

```
if (Still seats left) {
    let participant = self.createParticipant(self.items[indexPath.row])
    participant.OnWaitingList = nil
    participant.OnWaitingListAt = nil
    Register and so on
}
```

In [Amazons documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) in 'Save Behavior Options' it states:

The AWS Mobile SDK for iOS supports the following save behavior options:

AWSDynamoDBObjectMapperSaveBehaviorUpdate: Does not affect unmodeled attributes on a save operation; passing a nil value for the modeled attribute will remove it from the corresponding item in DynamoDB. By default, the Object Mapper uses this behavior.

So setting these values is more of a work-around than a solution.